# Angular put request occurs an HttpErrorResponse but executing the code

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented a change password method, which one changes the password of the user in the database. If I executing the method, the password was successfully changed, but I got the following error (see screenshot). I read a couple of articles on stackoverflow. Most of them says that I have to change the response type to text`{ responseType: 'text' }`, but this isn't working in my case.

[image]

user.service.ts

```
changePassword(newPW: string, userId: number) {
        return this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/user/reset/password?newPw="+newPW+ "&userId="+ userId, { responseType: 'text' });
    }
```

accountComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.css']
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  public user!: User;
  public name!: string;
  public hide: boolean = true;
  public hideNewPw: boolean = true;
  public hideConfirmPw: boolean = true;
  private _unsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  constructor(private userservice: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.userservice.user;
    this.name = this.user.forename.toUpperCase() + ' ' + this.user.surename.toUpperCase();
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    if (this.user.password === f.value.currentPassword && f.value.newPassword === f.value.confirmNewPassword) {
      this.userservice.changePassword(f.value.newPassword, this.user.userId)
      .subscribe();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your response seems is a JSON, remove the `{ responseType: 'text' }`

Comment: @Yong Shun If I change the response type to json or removing the whole response type, the issue isn't solved. Got the same error

Comment: @Yong Shun and the API sends me this text after successfully reseting the password: "password was successfully reseted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `put` method the options object is the 3rd parameter.

```
httpClient.put(url, body, options)
```

So you need to pass the `{ responseType: 'text' }` as the 3rd argument.

Cheers